# Only White Triangles Draw After Shader Abstraction

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

I have been following a YouTube tutorial on using OpenGL and incorporating it into an existing project. Everything draws correctly when I declare the shader source code as a hard-coded c-string, but when I got to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=greXpRqCTKs&list=PLPaoO-vpZnumdcb4tZc4x5Q-v7CkrQ6M-&index=6) video on abstracting the shaders into their own class and files, I am suddenly only getting white triangles. I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I copy-pasted the exact shader code into a text file.

I use the code suggested in the video above from [this](https://insanecoding.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-read-in-file-in-c.html) blog to read in the files:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cerrno>

std::string get_file_contents(const char *filename)
{
  std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
  if (in)
  {
    std::string contents;
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    contents.resize(in.tellg());
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    in.read(&contents[0], contents.size());
    in.close();
    return(contents);
  }
  throw(errno);
}
```

I have no errors in compiling, linking, or reading the shader files, so I am pretty stumped. I have looked into some similar questions on here and all of the answers either do not pertain to my usage or do not fix the issue. The shader files and how I use the shaders are listed below. I appreciate any help you can give! <3

**default.vert**

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 col;
out vec4 vertColor;
void main()
{
   gl_Position = vec4(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, 1.0);
   vertColor   = vec4(col.x, col.y, col.z, 1.0);
}
```

**default.frag**

```
#version 330 core
in vec4 vertColor;
out vec4 FragColor;
void main()
{
   FragColor = vertColor;
}
```

**shader.h**

```
#include "gl/glew.h"

class Shader {
public:
    GLuint ID;

    Shader(const char*, const char*);
    ~Shader();
    void activate();
    void deactivate();
};
```

**shader.cpp**

```
#include "shader.h"
#include "gl/glew.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cerrno>

std::string get_file_contents(const char* filename)
{
    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (in)
    {
        std::string contents;
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        contents.resize(in.tellg());
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        in.read(&contents[0], contents.size());
        in.close();
        return(contents);
    }
    throw(errno);
}

Shader::Shader(const char* vertexFilename, const char* fragmentFilename) {
    // read in the shader files
    std::string vertexSourceString = get_file_contents(vertexFilename);
    std::string fragmentSourceString = get_file_contents(fragmentFilename);
    const char* vertexSource = vertexSourceString.c_str();
    const char* fragmentSource = fragmentSourceString.c_str();

    // create vertex shader
    unsigned int vertexShader;
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // create fragment shader
    unsigned int fragmentShader;
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    // link shaders together
    ID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ID, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(ID, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(ID);

    // cleanup
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
}

Shader::~Shader() {
    glDeleteProgram(ID);
}

void Shader::activate() {
    glUseProgram(ID);
}

void Shader::deactivate() {
    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

In **main.cpp**

```
const char* defaultVertexShaderSource = "../../../res/shaders/default.vert";
const char* defaultFragmentShaderSource = "../../../res/shaders/default.frag";
Shader defaultShader = Shader(defaultVertexShaderSource, defaultFragmentShaderSource);
```

I then pass this shader object through the render functions where it is used to draw squares that represent the spaces on a chess board. The shader is utilized in the following way:

```
shader.activate();
glBindVertexArray(vertex_array);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertex_buffer_data.size() / 2);
shader.deactivate();
```

Edit: Per Botje's comment: here is the complete graphical pipeline code:

```
GLuint vertex_buffer, vertex_array;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array);
glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer);

std::vector<float> vertex_buffer_data;

glm::vec3 top_right_corner = top_left_corner + square_top_right_offset;
glm::vec3 bottom_left_corner = top_left_corner + square_bottom_left_offset;
glm::vec3 bottom_right_corner = top_left_corner + square_bottom_right_offset;
glm::vec3 color = (is_black) ? BLACK_SQUARE_COLOR : WHITE_SQUARE_COLOR;

std::vector<glm::vec3*> vertices = {&top_left_corner, &top_right_corner, &bottom_left_corner, &top_right_corner, &bottom_left_corner, &bottom_right_corner};
for (auto vertex : vertices) {
    vertex_buffer_data.push_back(vertex->x);
    vertex_buffer_data.push_back(vertex->y);
    vertex_buffer_data.push_back(vertex->z);
    vertex_buffer_data.push_back(color.x);
    vertex_buffer_data.push_back(color.y);
    vertex_buffer_data.push_back(color.z);
}

glBindVertexArray(vertex_array);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer_data.size() * sizeof(float), vertex_buffer_data.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

shader.activate();
glBindVertexArray(vertex_array);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertex_buffer_data.size() / 2);

shader.deactivate();
glBindVertexArray(0);
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer);
```

Comment: This is not an [mre]. Where is the code that sets up your vertex buffers? Where do you set up your VAO and attribute bindings? Random guess though: change the initialization of `defaultShader` to `Shader defaultShader(defaultVertexShaderSource, defaultFragmentShaderSource);` because you currently create and destroy a temporary, leaving your `defaultShader` referencing a deleted Shader object.

Comment: I have added the code you asked for. I don't understand what is different in your initialization of ```defaultShader``` though. It looks to be what I have in the code already. If you mean I should move it from the stack to the heap, it is in the program's main function and would not be removed from the stack until the program exits.

Comment: The code in your question allocates a temporary object, uses the copy constructor and then destructs the temporary. Mine directly initializes the variable  and crucially does not call the destructor

Answer (score -1):

As Botje pointed out, the problem was the shader initialization was being deleted before it was being used. By declaring the shader as a heap variable, the program works as intended.

Comment: You mean you did `Shader *shader = new Shader(...)`? Did you try my suggestion?